# Magento 1.9 How to set session and clear session in login and logout

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, session

I would like to set session during login action and clear session during logout action.

By  googling I understand the following code will help setting the session and clearing the session.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyValue($myValue);
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsMyValue();
```

But I don't know what are the files and where exactly I need to include these code to set session during login and clear session during logout.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

Use event observer to set your custom session value (Refer this tutorial for [**Event observers**](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105))

**For customer login**

use

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <your_unqiue_event_name>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>logout</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </your_unqiue_event_name>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>

        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <your_unqiue_event_name1>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>login</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </your_unqiue_event_name1>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Then set/unset your custom session value

in

```
public function login()
{
     ..... 
     Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyValue($myValue);
     .....
}

public function logout()
{
    .....
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsMyValue();
    .....
}
```

Comment: Where do i keep this xml file

Comment: @shakthydoss refer the tutorial link, you will get better understand of magento event observer

Comment: Is there any way to find admin logout users from magento using event observer?